# How to abort makefile without error message

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, abort

How can I abort makefile from continuing other targets, if certain condition is met in current target.

For example:

```
Step01:
    @# Do something

Step02: Step01_Output
    @# Check that Step01_output meet certain condition, otherwise, abort

Step03: Step02
    @# Do somethings (of course if did not abort in Step02)

# And so on
```

I tried using "exit" with status 0 ==> But it continues nevertheless!
I tried using "exit 1" or other exist status ==> It aborts, but gives error message at output.
I want to abort, but still not to give an error message at make calling shell.
I tried also to set env variable from Step02  and surround Step03 and after within if check like this:

```
ifneq ($(ToAbort),1) 
Step03:
...
StepN

endif
```

Unfortunately, it seems that make did not even look at the condition or the variable value has not been transferred between targets.

Any ideas? May be through adding additional target or so?

Comment: Please provide a real-world example instead of pseudocode, there's a chance this could be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: After some struggling, I think I've come around to @bobbogo's way of thinking about this: use `make` itself to the maximum extent possible. I myself have used `exit 127` to abort a recipe mid-way through when some conditions were met, but decided after some time that I couldn't live with the error message and the non-zero exit from `make` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure your thinking is correct on this one.
Leave the culling of work up to *make*.

However,
you can express what you requested with a smattering of *shell* and recursive *make* (sorry).
You want to express "if *a* completes with/without error, then we are done, else carry on with *b*."

```
Step01:
    command1
    command2
    command3 && ${MAKE} Step02
    command4

Step02:
    cmd5
    cmd6 && ${MAKE} Step03

⋮
```

Note those ampersands.
`if command3; then ${MAKE} Step02; fi` does not do what you want.
If the *make* fails,
you do not want to continue into *command4*.

P.S. Don't forget to mark those steps as PHONY if they aren't real files.

Answer (score 0):

I think make exits only when all the targets are created or any error arises.
By the way, commands are run in sub shells so that using`exit' will not cause make to exit.